# New update available on Expo, infinite downloading

Tags: expo

I'm new to developping with Expo. That new that I haven't started developping yet because of an issue.

I followed a tutorial which shows how to use Expo to see how our app is doing. (https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4902061-developpez-une-application-mobile-react-native/4915601-demarrez-votre-application-sur-smartphone-tablette)

Everything works fine until I try to actually see how my app is doing.

I scan the QR code given by Expo (on the Expo's application), and it displays the splash screen and the following message : **"New update available, downloading..."** (it never changes, even after an hour)

I have no idea about what is going on. If someone already met this issue and knows how to fix it I would be glad to know.

I use **Expo SDK 39.0.0**

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5rAy.png) https://youtu.be/8zh164zwwro Try this video! My problem was solved after following the instruction of this video It was solved by installing Android SDK Tools (Obsolete). This can work for "How to fix Android SDK manager tool not found?". I had to waste my whole day looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found what was the problem : I tried to used the wrong connection type. As I was on a local network I thought I should use LAN connection but when I clicked on "tunnel" connection and reloaded the app it worked.

Comment: where do you click on "tunnel"?

Comment: I found it on the interface, but it was a long time ago and I don't remember exactly where. But there is a source that can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734935/how-do-you-set-default-connection-to-tunnel-with-expo

Comment: When I used just `expo start` instead of `expo start tunnel`, the problem went away on both iOS and Android 

Answer (score 8):

In my case,

1. Close the react-native debugger.
2. Run the app again in the browser debugger. reload app from browser debugger (App will start properly)
3. Connect react-native degugger

Answer (score 5):

tried cache clearing in expo app,reinstalling, changing connection type and everything nothing works but once restart the machine problem solved ( ubuntu 20.04 )

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem uninstall and install again the Expo App from Play Store

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am getting the error as a result of an issue with EAS Update: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17461

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error multiple times during my carrier in development with expo, here is the solution I use, and for me it works most of them times.

1. First you have to run these commands in your terminal

`brew update`

`brew uninstall watchman`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyDesktopFolder`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyDeveloperFiles`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyDownloadsFolder`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyRemovableVolumes`

`sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicySysAdminFiles`

2. After running all the commands above, you have to reinstall watchman like this:

`brew install watchman watchman`

3. Restart your computer (This is important! Otherwise it would not work )
4. Your computer will ask to allow the `WATCHMAN` access to multiple locations in your computer. Give permission to all of them.
5. That is all, restart your Expo application, and it will run as expected!

Comment: This was my exact problem and this solution resolved it. The symptoms where similar like when phone can't access the expo server. The difference is that the Expo Go app loads the splash image, but then it times out waiting for JS file to load, and the error message says to check if expo server is running and that it's accessible from the phone. There is also no logs in expo server console.

Comment: Glad you have managed to resolve it! This is weird issue, but this solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The issue came back, even after this resolved it briefly. The next thing I tried, which seems to work, is to just force quit the iOS simulator, and restart my app as usual with npx expo start. I'm on a M1 Mac -- might have something to do with it.

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the version property in app.json under expo.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
}
```

removing version did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine this seems to have been caused by a browser tab having Javascript debugger on. I closed the tab, and then the app started ok again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an infinite loop that is running. Search for it by commenting looping parts from your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you're use deep link in your app. i was ignoring this warning

Warning: Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project’s Expo config (`app.config.js` or `app.json`) for production apps.

but after adding `scheme` in both files app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seeems that many cause can be the root of the issue.
Worth mentioning it happens after have installed update from command line.
For me was enough go to phone setting and under Expo Go clean the data, so the app was forced to bundle back the app.

Answer (score 0):

Manually typing the expo link which is exp://(Address shown in your console) in the expo go app worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, windows 10 + android expo app:
just typing "r" (reload app) at windows terminal and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. I have resolved the issue by updating expo go app in android emulator. Once updated, I reopened the app and it worked fine.