# How do you set default `CONNECTION` to `tunnel` with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

When running `expo ios`, the default connection type is `LAN`. Via app.json, metro.config.js, or .env, how does one configure type `tunnel` to be the default?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? If so, you should answer your own question for future searchers.

Comment: I didn't :/ I just put up with clicking on 'tunnel' on restarts for the time being.

Answer (score 22):

It's been a while since you asked this question so I assume you have already figure out the answer. You need to change the "start" script in package.json to "expo start --tunnel".

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and I tried to change my scripts to:

```json
{
   "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  }
}
```

But it didn't work. I then had to run the command directly:

```bash
npx expo start --tunnel
```

Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, on July 25th, the Expo team announced "[Sunsetting the Web UI for Expo CLI](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206)".

So, only the commands typed in the terminal stand:

```
"start": "expo start --tunnel",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"eject": "expo eject"
```

or writing them in the `package.jason` --> scripts, as @porkupan suggested.